# Serialize Flex Objects to Save/Restore Application State

Tags: actionscript, flex3

Is it possible to serialize a hierarchy of objects in Flex, send the binary data to a URL for storage/retrieval on/from a server, and deserialize the data to restore the objects' original state?

I know it's possible to convert the objects into an XML format (haven't tried it yet), but I'm hoping to avoid parsing XML and rebuilding the objects manually.  It would be nice to have functionality which can serialize/deserialize objects to a simple binary format (I did something similar in the past in Java, though not quite as easily as I would have liked).  The 'eval' function in Perl is similar to what I'm looking for, sans saving code, of course.

In pseudo-code, here's what I would like to do:

```
private var contentToSave:HBox = new HBox();

private function saveState(event:Event):void {
    var toSave:HBox = this.contentToSave;
    var data:? = /* serialize 'toSave' ActionScript classes to binary data*/;
    sendDataToServer(data, filename);
}
private function restoreState(filename):void {
    var data:? = getDataFromServer(filename);
    var savedData:HBox = /* deserialize binary 'data' to ActionScript classes */;
    this.contentToSave = savedData;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the JSON based `serialization` package in [ascorelib](http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src/com/adobe/serialization).

> [...]but I'm hoping to avoid parsing XML and rebuilding the objects manually

AS handles XML just like any other native type. Rest assured. XML is the preferred way of dealing with data you will be pulling off and putting back on a server. Of course, the `ascorelib` gives you a JSON class -- so you may want to look at that as well.

> The 'eval' function in Perl is similar to what I'm looking for, sans saving code, of course.

IIRC, `eval` is part of the ECMAScript specification (and you will find it in Javascript). But not in AS3.0. It was there to a certain extent in some previous version(s?) but is no longer supported.

Comment: thanks for the response!  Just to make sure I understand: if I convert the HBox (from the example) to XML and save this on a server, I can retrieve the XML and restore the HBox (and all children) as an object without parsing or doing any manual object creation?

Comment: No, you cannot just convert a HBox to XML. You'll have to implement a function for that. What I meant was XML handling is painless in AS3.

Comment: It looks like the JSON libraries in ascorelib are what I was looking for.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [ByteArray.writeObject()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#writeObject%28%29). which saves the passed object in AMF format into the byte array. I have not used this function too much, I don't exactly know what kind of objects it can serialize, but definitely not all.